# BufferedReader - Block at end of stream

Tags: sockets, clojure, bufferedreader, channel

I'm writing some functions that use clojure.async to abstract away from reading/writing to sockets. My intent is that values can be put into a channel to have them written, and popped from a channel to be read. This way, the user doesn't need to worry about `Reader`s/`Writer`s.

The code below reads from a socket in a loop, forwarding anything it reads into a channel. The channel is returned so it can be read from. My problem is, when the end of the stream is reached, instead of blocking, it sits there spinning until something can be read. If I have a few of these processes going, it makes a noticeable performance issue on my computer.

The easiest way I could see to fix this is somehow have `BufferedReader`'s `readLine` block on EOF instead of returning `nil`. From what I can see though, this isn't possible. That doesn't surprise me though, since blocking on EOF for most streams would be very odd. For socket streams though, EOF doesn't seem to have a specific meaning, since messages can still be received even once the EOF is reached.

Is there a way to prevent the loop from spinning while waiting for input once the EOF has been reached?

```
(ns chat.so-example
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as a :refer [chan go >!]])
  (:import [java.net Socket SocketException]
           [java.io BufferedReader InputStreamReader InputStream]))

(defn valid-message? [msg]
  (and (some? msg)
       (not (empty? msg))))

(defn new-input-chan [^Socket sock]
  (let [^InputStream in (.getInputStream sock)
        buff-reader     (BufferedReader. (InputStreamReader. in))
        in-chan         (chan)]
    (go
      (try
        (while (.isConnected sock) ; This spins when EOF is reached
          (let [line (.readLine buff-reader)]
            (when (valid-message? line)
              (>! in-chan line))))
        (catch SocketException se
          (#_"Handle exception"))
        (finally
          (a/close! in-chan))))
    in-chan))
```

Comment: Rich Hickey several times stated that this is not a good idea and not what he had in mind for core.async. You might want to watch his core.async talks to fully understand the rationale behind this. Have a look at Zach Tellmans libraries like manifold and aleph which implement the abstraction you are looking for and do integrate with core.async.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin do you have links to said talks?  I'd like to watch them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing spinning here is you. None of the methods in the classes you are using spin. Read the documentation for [isConnected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()) and [isClosed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed()) or [isInputShutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isInputShutdown()) and a solution should become clear. It also would have helped you to read the description of [readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), which is very clear about what it returns when there is no more input to read.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this answer is supposed to be answering. I *did* read the docs for `getLine`. Of note is the part "returns...null if the end of the stream has been reached". When null is returned indicating the end of the stream, `(valid-message? line)` becomes false, causing the loop to run out of control since it's no longer parking at `>!`. I want to know how to prevent the rapid looping. And I realized my mistake in using `inConnected`, and tried only looping while the socket is open instead of connected, and the behavior remained the same.

Comment: This is also a link on answer, which you know is poor.

Comment: When you read the end of the stream, you are at the end of the stream. There will never ever be another message incoming. That is what the end of stream means. It does not mean "nothing there right now".

Comment: Unless the EOF isn't happening when I think it is, I've been able to read from the socket, even once I've gotten an EOF.

Comment: That simply doesn't happen. For a socket, reading past "data that has arrived so far" blocks. It doesn't create an EOF condition. EOF means that you have read past "all data that will ever exist". Once you get nil from `readLine`, you will never get back anything but nil in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.BufferedReader.ready()` method can check whether there's more to be read, even after `EOF`. Also, `Sockets` can be coerced into `BufferedReader` simply using `(clojure.java.io/reader socket)`. Same for writer.

I'm not very familiar with `core.async` though, so no idea if that helps.